# Schema Registry persistence after reboot

Tags: apache-kafka, persistence, restart, reboot, confluent-schema-registry

I just finished this tutorial to use Kafka and Schema Registry :http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-avro-schema-registry/index.html
I also played with Conlfuent Platform : https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp.html

Everything works fine, until I rebooted my Virtual Machine (VMBOX) :
**All schemas/subjects have been deleted (or disappeared) after I rebooted.**

I read that Schema Registry to not store itself the data but use Kafka to do that. Of course, as I work for the moment only on my laptop, Kafka was also shutdown during the machine reboot.

**Is it normal behavior, do we have to expect to RE-store all schemas all the time we reboot??? (-> maybe last version so!)**

**Do anybody have good best practices about that?**

**How persistence of schemas can be managed to avoid this problem ?**

Environment : Ubuntu 16... , Kafka 2.11.1.0.0, Confluent Platform 4.0

Thanks a lot

nota: I already read this topics which discuss about keeping schema's ID, but has I don't recover any schemas, it's not a problem of Ids : [Confluent Schema Registry Persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275334/confluent-schema-registry-persistence/45435199#45435199)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schema Registry persists its data in Kafka.

Therefore your question becomes, why did you lose your data from Kafka on reboot.

My guess would be you've inadvertently used `/tmp` as the data folder. Are you using Confluent CLI in your experiments?

Comment: You were simply totally right! I used confluent which locate the schemas temporarly: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-cli (end of the page).
So I updated this variable CONFLUENT_CURRENT and then everything reappeared after reboot!
Thanks a lot!